# compare two files and print unmatched line number?

Tags: linux, command-line

how can I print difference line number?

example- compare File 1 vs File2 and print line no. for differnce record present in file 2.

In file1:

```
userD
user3
userA
user1
userB
```

and

In file2:

```
user3
userB
userX
user1
user7
```

expected result:-
    difference in file2 is for line number 3,5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bash-4.1$ cat file1
userD
user3
userA
user1
userB

bash-4.1$ cat file2
user3
userB
userX
user1
user7

bash-4.1$ awk 'NR==FNR{Arr[$0]++;next}!($0 in Arr){print FNR}' file1  file2
3
5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ grep -n -v -f file1 file2
3:userX
5:user7
```

This means "give me all lines in `file2` that are not (`-v`) in `file1` (`-f file1`), with line numbers (`-n`), please".

If you only want the first part of that, filter through `cut`:

```
$ grep -n -v -f file1 file2 | cut -d ':' -f 1
3
5
```

Comment: Another One of these questions that a proposal worked but OP left the door open as he left

Answer (score 0):

```
sdiff file1 file2 | sed -n '/|/='
```

We do a side-by-side diff on the two files and only for the lines that differ we display the line num.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what kind of shell you are using...assuming bash shell

```
let line=0
for item in $(cat file2)
do
 line+=1
 grep $item file1 > /dev/null 2>&1
 [ $? -ne 0 ] && echo -n "${line},"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash script to print the line numbers for any lines in file2 which are not in file1:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# read files into arrays
mapfile -t a < file1
mapfile -t b < file2

# copy file1 into an associative array
declare -A lines
for i in "${!a[@]}" ; do
  lines["${a[$i]}"]=$i
done

# loop through file2 and report any line numbers for lines missing from file1
for i in "${!b[@]}" ; do
    if [ "${lines[${b[$i]}]}" == "" ] ; then
        # echo line number for extra line
        echo $(($i + 1))
    fi
done
```